# Kubernetes CoreDNS rewrite CNAME record rules for specific namespace

Tags: kubernetes, url-rewriting, coredns

For my project I need to overwrite CNAME DNS records with CoreDNS for internal cluster DNS resolution. 
I can do this globally for a cluster like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
        data:
        Corefile: |
            # Add your CoreDNS customizations as import files.
            # Refer to https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cluster_dns for details.
            .:53 {
                rewrite name test.example.com example.namespace1.svc.cluster.local
                ...
            }
...
```

So in the whole cluster all requests to `test.example.com` will be sended to service: `example.namespace1.svc.cluster.local`.

Is it possible to define rewrite rule only for specific namespace?
For example I want only `namespace1` to have this rewrite rule in place.

Thank you!

Comment: I require something similar.   Have you gotten this to work in a helm chart?

Comment: Unfortunately no, in the end, we changed our application code from `test.example.com` to `test-example-com`, which is name of the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible to have DNS per namespace by modifying the configMap of core DNS because coreDNS is a cluster wide DNS . If your use case is to expose services via hostname then you can explore [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)

Comment: I need to do this inside cluster, because our system is pointing to  `test.example.com` inside cluster and in the service name it is not possible to set names with dots.
Change of the  `test.example.com`  is not possible right now from the application point.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin may help you: https://github.com/kinjelom/coredns-recursor

> The `recursor` resolves domains using defined IP addresses or resolving other mapped domains using defined resolvers.

[image]